# SSL certificate for AWS Route 53 NS record

Tags: ssl, nameserver, amazon-route53

I have a client who has asked me to set up a subdomain that delegates to a set of nameservers for handling email. This is a little bit ouside of the work I normally do.

They've explicitly told to me to ensure that the subdomain is set up with SSL. This seems like a strange ask to me because of the NS record type. AWS Route 53 doesn't give me any options to select a certificate when configuring a subdomain and semantically speaking, how
could you apply an SSL cert for this scenario when you don't control the application servers?

Answer (score 3):

> AWS Route 53 doesn't give me any options to select a certificate when
>   configuring a subdomain and semantically speaking, how could you apply
>   an SSL cert for this scenario when you don't control the application
>   servers?

This isn't how it works. Your client (or whomever controls the application servers) needs to to this. It has nothing to do with DNS.

Route53 deals with DNS and DNS only. SSL is something that needs to be configured on whatever application server DNS is pointing at (email, http, etc).

You'll need to:

1. Work with the client to understand their needs.
2. Research and *understand* the technologies at hand instead of shooting in the dark.
3. Implement systems to fulfill your client's needs.

If any of this is above your head, then hire someone to help you out.

Comment: Thank you @EEAA - your explanation was my understanding, but I couldn't find anything explicitly stating that fact.

Comment: @th3morg You're in for a huge disappointment if you expect to be able to Google and find an exact answer that explains every situation you encounter. This is why Step #2 above is of utmost importance. You're providing services to your clients that you don't understand. That's troubling. So do yourself and your clients a favor and *learn* about the technologies you're selling, before selling them. :)

Comment: Please do not patronize me. Not that this is your concern, but I'm a software developer and have a contract for application development. They've asked me to do this one thing that is a bit outside of the realm of that expectation and I've been clear with them that this is not my expertise and that I will be seeking out advice. My intention behind asking this question was to validate my understanding and to be able to communicate back with the client with a little more information. Thank you for assisting me in being able to do that.

Comment: @th3morg I'm not patronizing you. I'm sure you're a very talented developer, and I understand that you are being asked to do something that is outside of your wheelhouse. It is clear, though, that you only did a mere modicum of research into this before asking your question. Of course R53 doesn't have a place to "select a certificate" because doing so makes absolutely no sense when it comes to DNS. Anyway, take the opportunity and *learn*. Dig in, play around, mess things up. At the end of the day, you'll be a better software developer for it.